# uboot mmc write issue on beagleboard black

Tags: u-boot, beagleboard

I have some toubles with mmc write on beagleboard black.

Here is the problem :

```
U-Boot# usb start
(Re)start USB...
USB0:   scanning bus 0 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 1 Storage Device(s) found
U-Boot# fatload usb 0 ${loadaddr} ${rootfs_file}
reading rootfs.ext4
18742272 bytes read in 12384 ms (1.4 MiB/s)
U-Boot# mmc dev 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
U-Boot# mmc part

Partition Map for MMC device 1  --   Partition Type: DOS

Part    Start Sector    Num Sectors     UUID            Type
  1     63              1028097         00000000-01     0c Boot
  2     1028160         1028160         00000000-02     83
  3     2056320         1686825         00000000-03     83
U-Boot# mmc dev 1 2
switch to partitions #2, OK
mmc1(part 2) is current device
U-Boot# mmc write $loadaddr 0x0 0x20000

MMC write: dev # 1, block # 0, count 131072 ... MMC: block number 0xffff exceeds max(0x800)
0 blocks written: ERROR
```

So why ? Partition 2 is supposed to be 64MB

moreover

```
U-Boot# mmc info
Device: OMAP SD/MMC
Manufacturer ID: fe
OEM: 14e
Name: MMC02
Tran Speed: 52000000
Rd Block Len: 512
MMC version 4.41
High Capacity: No
Capacity: 1 MiB <=== ??? WHY ???
Bus Width: 4-bit
```

Thanks for your replys

Fred

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK "mmc write" performs raw writes to the MMC device. It does not perform write via the filesystem. There is no "write" support to most of the filesystem access commands. Only ext4 seems to have "write" operation (but I have not personally tested this). 
The "mmc write" you performed probably overwrote the MMC partition table.

Comment: Hi, where is the partition table saved ? Is there any offset for the partition table ?